# Open a progress bar until function task ends

Tags: python, wxpython, progress-bar

I have an event listener on left double click inside a wx.Grid that opens a dialog box to confirm the change. If the user clicks on "Yes" I call a function that takes around 6 seconds to execute, meanwhile the window freezes. What I want to do is to open a progress bar so the user can wait until the function finishes its task, or better, have the progress bar in the dialog box.

I have no idea where to start as I've never needed a progress bar until now.

A lot of the solutions I've looked at suggest threading, but I'm pretty inexperienced with threads in Python.

I'm hoping someone will be able to give me a hand displaying the progress for a running task using wxPython.

Here is my code so far:

```
def OnCellLeftDClick(self, evt):
    if evt.GetCol() == 17:
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Do you want to change " + self.GetCellValue(evt.GetRow(), 1) + " bid?",'Updater',wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        if result == wx.ID_YES:
            from chanbeBid import changeBidTb
            changeBidTb(self.GetCellValue(evt.GetRow(), 1), self.GetCellValue(evt.GetRow(), 16))

    evt.Skip()
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the _thread module to create the new thread and pubsub to handle the communication between the threads. One way to do it is shown below. I added a few comments to the code.

```
import wx
import time
import _thread
from pubsub import pub

seconds = 10

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Just a button to start counting
        """
        super().__init__(None, title='Counting until...')
        self.panel  = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Count', pos=(50, 50))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCount)

        ## This will subscribe the window to the message 'Finish counting'.
        ## Thus, everytime the message is broadcast the self.Pass method
        ## will be executed.
        pub.subscribe(self.Pass, 'Finish counting')

    def OnCount(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Do you want to count?", 
                              style=wx.YES_NO|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
            self.count()
        else:
            pass

    def count(self):
        ## Creates and starts a new thread that will execute the self.wait
        ## method. Notice that the thread is started before the ProgressDialog
        ## because the ProgressDialog will keep the main thread busy
        _thread.start_new_thread(self.wait, (seconds,))

        ## ProgressDialog that will keep running until maxV is reached or
        ## until self.keepGoing is set to False
        maxV = 100
        dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Progress dialog example",
                                     "An informative message",
                                     maximum = maxV,
                                     parent=self,
                                     style = 0
                                     | wx.PD_APP_MODAL
                                    #| wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
                                    #| wx.PD_CAN_SKIP
                                     | wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME
                                    #| wx.PD_ESTIMATED_TIME
                                    #| wx.PD_REMAINING_TIME
                                    #| wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE
                                     )
        self.keepGoing = True
        count = 0
        while self.keepGoing and count < maxV:
            count += 1
            wx.MilliSleep(250)
            wx.SafeYield()
            (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count)
        dlg.Destroy() 

    def wait(self, secs):
        ## This is the function that is executed by the new thread
        ## when it finishs the wx.CallAfter method broadcast the message
        ## 'Finish counting' that triggers self.Pass as mentioned above.
        time.sleep(secs)
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'Finish counting')

    def Pass(self):
        ## Changes self.keepGoing to false so the ProgressDialog is destroyed. 
        self.keepGoing = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Regarding having the progress bar in the dialog window asking to proceed. This can be done but you need to build your custom dialog window and probably use `wx.Gauge` instead of `wx.ProgressDialog`. Also most probably you will want this custom window to be modal (freeze all other windows in the program so the user has to wait for the function running in the thread to finish). For this add the following method to the custom dialog class,

```
def ShowModal(self):
    """
    wx.Dialog behavior
    """
    self._disabler = wx.WindowDisabler(self)
    self.Show()
    self.eventLoop = wx.GUIEventLoop()
    self.eventLoop.Run()
```

and show the custom dialog in the same way as normal `wx.Dialog`, `custom_dialog.ShowModal()`

Comment: Thank you, for your answer but as I said I've never worked with Thread. The code works when run as a stand alone, but I can't integrate it in my existing script unfortunately. I've errors with the first line :/

Comment: Can you give a MWE of your app? What does the error that you get say?